How to update multiple records with the same values but using different values in the where clause
I have to update a large number of rows with the same values, but the values in the update where statement would be different for each row that needs to be updated.
For example col1 and col2 need to be updated to 0 and 1 respectively. This is for all updates.
WHERE col 3 = a, col4 =b and col5 =c

Not managed to do it, apart from using 73 separate update statements.
UPDATE [Mytable].[dbo].[DocumentRegistry]
SET [Document] = 1, [State] = 4 
WHERE [col1] = 'abc'  AND col2 = 'def'  AND col3 = 'ghi' ;

UPDATE [Mytable].[dbo].[DocumentRegistry] 
SET [Document] = 1, [State] = 4 
WHERE [col1] = '123'  AND col2 = '456'  AND col3 = '789' ;

UPDATE [Mytable].[dbo].[DocumentRegistry] 
SET [Document] = 1, [State] = 4 
WHERE [col1] = 'xyz'  AND col2 = 'fgh' AND col3 = 'dev';

and so on.......
I get the values for col1, col2, and col3 from this statement:
SELECT r.PNoID, r.DocumentID, r.RegistryID 
FROM Documents r WITH(NOLOCK) 
INNER JOIN UploadedDocuments d WITH(NOLOCK) ON r.Uniqueid = d.uniqueid
WHERE r.PNoID IN (xxxxxx,xxxxxx,xxxxxxx)

How can I do this?

How do you know what sets of (col1, col2, col3) values  in the WHERE clause you need to change? There are 73 of them... where do those 73 items come from?

The values will come from the results of the following query: SELECT r.PNoID, r.DocumentID, r.RegistryID
FROM Documents r WITH(NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN UploadedDocuments d WITH(NOLOCK)
ON r.Uniqueid = d.uniqueid
WHERE r.PNoID IN (xxxxxx,xxxxxx,xxxxxxx)

In that case, the "SQL Update query using joins" link in the box added above the question will tell you how to do this. But while I'm here, that with(nolock) isn't the automatic "go faster" option it seems you've been taught. You should probably stop using it.

The values that are returned using the select statement above provide the values for the where clause in the update statement, not to update col1, col2, col3. Thanks

That makes no difference. The link above is still the what you need to do. You can use the SQL you provided to craft an UPDATE instead of a SELECT and put literals you want in the SET clause. UPDATE statements can also use JOINs.
